# UIAutomator testmethod passes in alternate attempts

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I have written a method in Android UIAutomator project and pushed the corresponding jar file to Android device.I am calling the method from adb shell using following command "adb shell uiautomator runtest sample.jar -c com.practice.sample.Bluetooth#turnBluetoothOFF".The problem I have is, it works only alternate times.i.e, for first attempt it works and for the second attempt it fails with Exception "Cound not register UiAutomationService" and for the third attempt it again passes.

NOTE :
The above thing is working fine in other Android devices( Samsung Galaxy S3 4.2.2 , Samsung Galaxy S4).I face this issue only in Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.1 AT&T mobile.

Any work around or solution would be needful.

Code :

```
// Returns Switch object of passed Text
```

public UiObject getSwitch(String text) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

```
return new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))
.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(LinearLayout.class.getName()),text, true).getChild(
new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Switch.class.getName()));

    }


public void turnBluetoothOFF() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

    if (bluetoothStatus().matches("ON")) {
        getSwitch(getValue("BluetoothText")).click();
    }
```

I feel there is nothing to do with the code. Because same code works fine in all the devices. 
    }

Comment: could you post your code here ?

Answer (score 0):

4.1 is API level 16.
Most of the UIAutomator functions like matches() etc related to UIObject work with min API level 17.

Comment: There is nothing to do with matches() with the question posted. Because same thing goes well on othere API level 16 devices. The problem I feel is UIAutomator service is not released once it is used.For the first time it ges well , second time it fails, third time it passes and fourth time it fails.Alternately it passes.

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion:-

I tried below code in API 16 , It works fine.

```
    public void disableBT( UiObject btSwitch) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Disabling BT");
    if (btSwitch.getText().equals("ON"))
        btSwitch.click();       
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with the code.(Same thing I mentioned in my question too).What happens is for the first time when I trigger any method from command line, UIAutomator works fine but for the second attempt it fails with the Exception "Cound not register UiAutomationService". And If I try after this it works fine. The above behaviour is observed only in Samsung Galaxy S3 4.1.1 AT&T mobile , in remaining device it goes well.

Comment: try `adb kill-server` or reboot the device and try again.